# Meteor - Modify document upon expiration

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have users adding posts. Post looks like this (pseudo-code)

```
post = {
  _id: random,
  userId: userId,
  status: 'published',
  expiration: 'Date.now() + 30days'
};
```

I want posts to automatically change status to 'expired' after expiration time has been reached. How do I do that?
A blunt approach would be to set 1m interval check in Meteor.startup on the server.
But maybe there's a better solution? Maybe there's a Mongo-specific one (like the document updating itself or smth)?

Answer (score 1):

If your need to have your collection entries status updated is tied to specific logic catchable by hooks, you could use [meteor-collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks).

Otherwise, you could use cron job packages such as [mrt:cron](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/cron) or [meteor-synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron)